# Complex Assigning/Scheduling with CP Optimizer

Tags: python, optimization, cp, docplex

I've been trying to tackle a problem with CP optimizer, but I'm a little stuck:

I have projects with 200-300+ individual tasks with individual upstream and downstream dependencies. The tasks follow a pipeline (so the same type of tasks repeated for each unit from start to finish), but each task has an individual bid/duration (calculated in hours) that are different from one another. An employee can only work on one task at a time, and each task has a buffer time between the next task for transition time. The tasks
Each 'type of task' has a department start and end date, so the tasks can only be scheduled between those dates. Each department has a predetermined amount of artists within it.

Basically, I need to give each task a start and end date that co-insides with the department schedule and the employee's individual schedules, and optimize it so each department is completed by the scheduled end date.

Here is the code I have currently:

```
#Create model
mdl = CpoModel()

#Read CSV files
Crew = read_csv("CrewList.csv")
Task = read_csv("TaskList.csv")

#Convert column data to arrays
CrewList = Crew['Name'].tolist()
Dpt = Crew['Dpt'].tolist()
print('Name',CrewList)
TaskList = Task['ConcatTask'].tolist()
print('Tasks',TaskList)l
BidList = Task['Days'].tolist()
print('Tasks',BidList)
UpStream = Task['UpTask'].tolist()
DownStream = Task['DownTask'].tolist()

#Convert normal array to numpy type
u = np.array(UpStream)
d = np.array(DownStream)
#Concatenates each upstream and downstream task into an array
Precedences = np.vstack((UpStream,DownStream)).T

#Adds precedences to model
for x in Precedences:
    mdl.add(mdl.end_before_start(Precendences[x]))
```

Would love some general guidance or an example of a similar problem/model solved in CP. I appreciate any help!

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

A worker can be declared thanks a sequence Variable.

To tell a task can only be executed in a time segment (department) you have to forbid it overlaps a boundaries (start and end date) of a department. To achieve it you sue the constraint forbidExtent(it, f) where it is the interval variable of the task and f a piecewise fonction that is non-zero on the forbidden time interval. For this purpose be [s_i e_j) the (Suppose) successive departments time segments: is the piecewise function that is non_zero on [e_i, s_{i+1})